# Change specific textfield inside map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change a global state to a specific textfield like:

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({ name: '' });

const setName = () => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setValues({ name: e.target.value });
};

// map starts here
{editMode ? (
  <TextField
    id={`txt-${category.id}`}
    label="New name"
    value={values.name}
    onChange={setName()}
    margin="normal"
  />
)
```

So when I first click the textfield, it should set the value to both that textfield and global state to `category.name`, after typing it should set  the textfield value to the global state which is equal to the textfield I'm changing, how can I handle something like this?

Comment: Change this line `onChange={setName()}` to just `onChange={setName}` that way you are not executing the event-listener on render and you're actually listening for changes.

Comment: where are you updating global state?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem

```
type InputType = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement;

const updateField = (id: number, e: React.ChangeEvent<InputType>) => {
  setData(prevState => {
    return prevState.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) return { ...item, name: e.target.value };

      return item;
    });
  });
};

// inside the map 
value={data.find(i => i.id === category.id)!.name}
onChange={e => updateField(category.id, e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second function from setName and remove brackets from TextField's onChange property.

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({ name: '' });

const setName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setValues({ name: e.target.value });
};

// map starts here
{editMode ? (
  <TextField
    id={`txt-${category.id}`}
    label="New name"
    value={values.name}
    onChange={setName}
    margin="normal"
  />
)
```

OR...

You can also write one generic function for setting values instead of setName and the others:

```
const setAnyValue = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, field: string) => {
  setValues({ [field]: e.target.value });
};
```

And then onChange will look like:

```
    onChange={(e) => setAnyValue(e, 'name')}
```

Comment: The thing is that if I change the value in a map, it changes all the other values as well

Comment: @Daniell then you need to create an array of values with the length of the original array that you map from and assign each value to the value in the original array.

Comment: Do you have some example for this? it's the thing I couldn't get to work